# Doubts about table partitions

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

I am studying table partitions and I still have some things that I am not clear about.

I created a partition function that organizes the data for the last three months.

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION PartitioningBy3meses (datetime)
AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES (getdate()-90, getdate()-1);
GO
```

Scheme:

```
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME PartitionByVejes
AS PARTITION PartitioningBy3meses
TO (datosmuyviejos, datosviejos, [PRIMARY]);
GO
```

I used the wizard to partition an existing table and this is the code it generated for me:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[factura] DROP CONSTRAINT [PK__factura__3213E83F22FEA7FF] WITH ( ONLINE = OFF )

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[factura] ADD PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [ClusteredIndex_on_PartitionByVejes_637678578300644842] ON [dbo].[factura]
(
    [fecha]
)WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PartitionByVejes]([fecha])

DROP INDEX [ClusteredIndex_on_PartitionByVejes_637678578300644842] ON [dbo].[factura]
COMMIT TRANSACTION
GO
```

Doubts:

- Did the primary index become nonclustered in order to spread the data
  between the partitions?
- Why was the ClusteredIndex_on_PartitionByVejes_637678578300644842
  index created and then deleted?
- Does the data move on its own between the partitions as time goes by
  or do I have to do something to make it move?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Did the primary index become nonclustered in order to spread the data
> between the partitions?
>
> Why was the ClusteredIndex_on_PartitionByVejes_637678578300644842
> index created and then deleted?

No. A requirement for table partitioning is the [unique clustered index key must explicitly include the partitioning column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15#partitioning-clustered-indexes). Since `fecha` is not part of the existing primary key, the wizard preserved the existing primary key by recreating the primary key constraint with a nonclustered index and then creating a temporary clustered index to partition the data. The end result is a partitioned heap and nonpartitioned nonclustered primary key index. This may not be what you intended but the wizard will not make schema changes (e.g. add `fecha` to your primary key). You'll need to do that in advance of using the wizard or use T-SQL directly instead of using the wizard.

> Does the data move on its own between the partitions as time goes by
> or do I have to do something to make it move?

No, sliding window partition maintenance is not automatic. You'll need to schedule a T-SQL script that performs the maintenance as desired. SSMS includes a Manage Partition wizard, which is available with a right-click on the table once the table is partitioned.

Note the table and indexes must be storage aligned in order to perform sliding window maintenance efficiently. For the table in your question, this implies `fecha` must be part of the primary key. As you are new to table partitioning, I recommend you peruse the partitioning documentation to understand the restrictions and performance implication to make sure it's appropriate for your situation.

Comment: Also, even if the partition function use GETDATE() in its definition, SQL Server will evaluate the expression only once at creation time.  So, if the function is created on 2021-09-23 12:32:15, the partition boundaries will be defined as 2021-06-25 12:32:15,2021-09-22 12:32:15.

Comment: The latter I had my doubts but I forgot to ask.
I thought table partitioning would help me but I think it creates more problems for me than it solves.
My queries use the date to obtain the results, the dates are constantly searched in the future, in the last 3 months few times and rarely older. So I thought that partitioning the table would improve the response time.
I don't see a solution that doesn't involve deleting the partitions and the function and re-creating them daily.